# Why is there a color difference in DC glow discharge?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, plasma-physics

[image: DC discharge tube[Reddish region is anode glow, Bluish Region is cathode glow]]

Image:DC discharge tube[Reddish region is anode glow, Bluish Region is cathode glow]
I have recently started Plasma physics. I want to understand why there is a color difference in the anode glow and cathode glow, why there is a dark space?
Note that the pressure here is around 1 torr and Voltage 2.5kV.
I know here that color is due to recombination of electrons and ions and recovery from metastable state.What is essentially happening in this system is electrons are being accelerated due to electric field, there are knocking of other electrons from atoms, and some electrons are recombining and emitting light[Note that this is one of the reactions that are happening]
The gas used is Air[Nitrogen and oxygen]

Comment: This Wikipedia article might be a start? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glow_discharge